# Enforce s3 content type on presigned urls

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i am using `createPresignedPost` to let users upload media to my servers, and when it is uploaded s3 dispatches event to my processor lambda, but problem is that i can not validate content-type of the file. if i do not provide

```
['starts-with', '$Content-Type', `image/`]
```

to my `createPresignedPost` function, system automatically assigns `binary/octet-stream` content-type to object, which is a problem since i can not match it against my allowed content types (say jpg png and jpeg).

but if i add the condition user can manually send allowed content-type in headers while submitting file with different content-type, say they wrote `Content-Type: image/png` but actually sent executable file, which i can not validate even in processor lambda because, when i do `getObject` or `headObject` command on s3 for the file, it returns the content-type that was submitted in the form earlier (`image/png`) even though actual content-type is different.

I am pretty sure there has to be some kind of solution for this to actually know what the file type is without relying on user to give you valid information.
Is there something i am not seeing?

Comment: Which image library do you recommend? and isn't the whole point of presigned urls to not consume awful lot of memory loading file? i mean say my app allows 500MB videos to be uploaded, of course i can not load all that in lambda.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation but i am not sure that i agree with your statement about usage, principle that you mentioned is right but still it is mainly used for avoiding using uploading large base64s or multipart to lambda which has like 512MB max memory capacity and as of API Gateway it has 30 seconds timeout if i remember correctly, in which if you load 500MB of content, and process it, i think you will find no success, as of fargate, thats good recommendation but i am trying to stick with lambda, since it is easier to integrate with s3 notifications, and as there was lots of

Comment: recommendations for lambda as processor for the images uploaded by presigned urls, i think there should be some other way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you're trying to solve.

The issue is there is no relation between the content of the file and its `content-type` metadata.

What is important to understand, is that the `content-type` header is part of the HTTP standard.
It was designed to allow the server to offer information about the content type to the client.
The S3 implementation uses the object metadata to send this information when a client is requesting the object.

In a non-S3 implementation, the server has full control of the content.
In that situation, it evaluates the content and sends the type of information according to its logic.

S3 does not have this feature.
It accepts any type of content and any value in the object `content-type` metadata.
And when someone asks for that contact, it will receive the `content-type` informed originally.

To solve the issue, you'll need to receive the content, validate it, associate the correct type and upload it directly to S3.
As you mentioned in the comments, resigned URLs will not help you with that.

Comment: i have not tested s3 proxies though api gateway but i have worked with multer with express, and if content-type is only http request header why can't you alter content-type and just send different file object than original, i don't believe multer relies on http header to validate the file. are you sure there are no relation between file and its content/mime type

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. You can find the specifics of the header in the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-content-type).

Comment: The important thing to note is that: you used multer/express and it did all the heavy lifting for you. Evaluate the content and defined the content type. Multer/Express must be understood as one implementation of an HTTP server.

Comment: AWS S3 is another implementation of an HTTP Server. In the AWS S3 implementation, it delivers the content of the blob. If there is content-type metadata associated with the blob, it will send it. If there is no metadata associated with it, it will send a generic content type: `binary/octet-stream` for binary blobs.

Comment: it still takes few seconds to process the read stream but its better than nothing, if this might help in future for whomever might find this helpful.